# UIBezierPath translation transform gives wrong answer

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgpath

When I attempt to translate a path, to move it to an origin of {0, 0}, the resulting path bounds is in error. (Or, my assumptions are in error).

e.g. the path gives the following bounds info:

```
let bezier = UIBezierPath(cgPath: svgPath)
print(bezier.bounds)

// (0.0085, 0.7200, 68.5542, 41.1379)

print(bezier.cgPath.boundingBoxOfPath)

// (0.0085, 0.7200, 68.5542, 41.1379)

print(bezier.cgPath.boundingBox)

// (-1.25, -0.1070, 70.0360, 41.9650)
```

I (attempt to) move the path to the origin:

```
let origin = bezier.bounds.origin
bezier.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -origin.x, y: -origin.y))

print(bezier.bounds)

// (0.0, -2.7755, 68.5542, 41.1379)
```

As you can see, the `x origin` component is correct at 0. But, the `y component` (-2.7755) has gone all kittywumpus. It should be 0, non?

The same thing happens when I perform the transform on the `cgPath` property.

Does anyone know what kind of circumstances could cause a `UIBezierPath/CGPath` to behave like this when translated? After reading the Apple docs, it seems that `UIBezierPath/CGPath` do not hold a transform state; the points are transformed immediately when the transform is called.

Thanks for any help.

Background:

The path data is from `Font-Awesome` SVGs, via `PocketSVG`. All files parse, and most draw OK. But a small subset exhibit the above translation issue. I'd like to know if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong or silly before I go ferreting through the SVG parsing, path-building code looking for defects.

BTW I am not drawing at this stage or otherwise dealing with a context; I am building paths prior to drawing.

[edit]

To check that PocketSVG was giving me properly formed data, I passed the same SVG to SwiftSVG, and got the same path data as PocketSVG, and the same result:

```
let svgURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "fa-mars-stroke-h", withExtension: "svg")!
var bezier = UIBezierPath.pathWithSVGURL(svgURL)!
print(bezier.bounds)

// (0.0085, 0.7200, 68.5542, 41.1379)

let origin = bezier.bounds.origin
let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -origin.x, y: -origin.y)
bezier.apply(translation)
print(bezier.bounds)

// (0.0, -2.7755, 68.5542, 41.1379)
```

Once again, that y component should be 0, but is not. Very weird.

On a whim, I thought I'd try to apply a transformation **again. And, it worked!**

```
let translation2 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -bezier.bounds.origin.x, y: -bezier.bounds.origin.y)
bezier.apply(translation2)
print(bezier.bounds)

// (0.0, 0.0, 68.5542491336633, 41.1379438254997)
```

Baffling! Am I overlooking something really basic here?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same as you and is working for me in Xcode 8.3.2 / iOS 10

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's also working for me if I create a path with a rect. So it appears that, somehow, the path data itself is borked, and is causing UIBezierPath/CGPath to produce weird results. If so, it's weird that borked data could screw up the bounds in this way. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled myself with the same problem, I managed to solve it by using the following snippet of code (Swift 5). I tested on an organic bezier shape and it works as expected:

```
extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY) }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    func center(inRect rect:CGRect) {
        let rectCenter = rect.center
        let bezierCenter = self.bounds.center
        
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: rectCenter.x - bezierCenter.x, y: rectCenter.y - bezierCenter.y)
        self.apply(translation)
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bezier = UIBezierPath() // replace this with your bezier object

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shape.bounds = self.view.bounds
    shape.position = self.view.bounds.center

    bezier.center(inRect: shape.bounds)
    shape.path = bezier.cgPath
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shape)
}
```

It will display the shape in the center of the screen.